# SQLite Error 19: 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework

I am working on a C# application, and i am using entity framework to handle the database.
I have the following DB design in my project:

[image: db design]

I get a "Foreign Key Constraint Failed" error whenever i try do delete a row in the "rentals" table, and i cant figure out why.

My migration for the rentals table looks like this:

```
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Rentals",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
            .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
        CustomerId = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false),
        ProductsId = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false),
        DateAssigned = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "TEXT", nullable: false),
        Active = table.Column<bool>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Rentals", x => x.Id);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Rentals_Customers_CustomerId",
            column: x => x.CustomerId,
            principalTable: "Customers",
            principalColumn: "Id");
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Rentals_Products_ProductId",
            column: x => x.ProductId,
            principalTable: "Products",
            principalColumn: "Id");
    });    

modelBuilder.Entity("API.Entities.Rentals", b =>
    {
        b.HasOne("API.Entities.Customer", "Customer")
            .WithMany("Rentals")
            .HasForeignKey("CustomerId")
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction)
            .IsRequired();

        b.HasOne("API.Entities.Product", "Product")
            .WithMany("Rentals")
            .HasForeignKey("ProductId")
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction)
            .IsRequired();

        b.Navigation("Customer");

        b.Navigation("Product");
    });
```

Any ideas on what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Lean to debug properly. Catch the SQL and then execute it in SSMS and get the full error message. There is MORE in the error than you tell us, and it is also visible in VS (in the exception), except you ignore it. Look at all the properties for the exception.

Comment: @TomTom - "your SQLite client" rather than SSMS?

Comment: Ah, overloked that. Not sure what they use, but grab the SQL sent to the database and look at the INNNER EXCEPTIONS. THere is a LOT more info available.

Comment: When a foreign key constraint fails, it is usually because you have a dependency on the primary key found on Rentals, meaning there is likely a relationship you aren't showing us in your design. Between when you restarted and you had the error, you likely deleted a different row, that referenced this FK from rentals in that row.

That would explain the behaviour you describe. But is not "required" to be the issue.

I am not aware that the ORM can "glitch" on something so vital as a foreign key constraint. That would render the software useless for corporations

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) [mre] [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem to be a glitch.

Restarted VS and afterwards the error didnt appear again.